# Java open browser and get redirect url

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

is there any method/library/framework which allow me to open browser with some url and then get redirect url which have params like token, refresh token etc.?

What exactly i am trying: 
I have client_id and client_secret necessary to get OAUTH2 token but i do not have server, this will only desktop app and everything is about to get user to page where he will be able to push button and get redirected.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2 This might be useful for you

Comment: @sForSujit have you seen maybe tutorial, quickstart or something like that? I do not understand what they exactly want from me.

Comment: i found that library https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava

Comment: Thats's good. And thanks for sharing with us.